# How to add profile picture for customer in magento 1.7.0.2?

Tags: ce-1.7.0.2, customer

I want to add profile picture for all the customers who register into my magento website.
How to add profile picture for customer in magento 1.7.0.2?

Comment: Thnaks philwinkle for this reply, but these extentions does not provide uploading avatar/profile picture during registration. Requirement is something that provide uploading profile pictures during registration.

Comment: this module allows you to add profile picture to customers,    http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/advance-user-profiles.html

Answer (score 4):

There are a few ways of doing this:

**Set up an avatar customer attribute type** and modify registration / My account forms.

You will have to implement some code to do this, **but there is a *fantastic* walk-through** on SO over here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800766/customer-image-upload-and-resize-in-magento

The gist is

**Use a Magento Connect Extension**

- A free one: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16313/
- A semi-popular paid extension: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/user-profile-extended-notifications-newsletter-and-personalization.html

**Optionally, consider using a service like Gravatar**.

Gravatars are recognized by Wordpress, Disqus, Github and Stack Overflow. This allows you to not have to deal with data types and file uploaders, and instead display the Gravatar that is associated to their registered email address.

Implementing gravatars with PHP is quite simple. PHP provides strtolower(), md5(), and urlencode() functions, allowing us to create the gravatar URL with ease. Assume the following data:

```
$email = "someone@somewhere.com";
$default = "http://www.somewhere.com/homestar.jpg";
$img_size = 40;
```

You can construct your gravatar url with the following php code:

```
$grav_url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" . md5( strtolower( trim( $email ) ) ) . "?d=" . urlencode( $default ) . "&s=" . $img_size;
```

Once the gravatar URL is created, you can output it whenever you please:

```
<img src="<?php echo $grav_url; ?>" alt="" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I came across an extension for the same. I installed it on 1.9.0.1 and it worked like a charm. Here is the link:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/customer-profile-pic-crop.html

Comment: The extension is really useful. +1 for this

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Medma Customer Avatar module. It's free, install is done in a minute.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/catalog/product/view/id/16313/

Comment: Its not free. It charges $9